# Why are there more types in my ntoskrnl binary than my fltMgr binary?

Tags: ida

I need the `CONTROL_AREA` Windows SDK structure to reverse `fltMgr.sys`. I see it in my `ntoskrnl.i64` but not my `fltMgr.i64` despite the fact they both only have `ntddk64_win7` type library loaded. Why does my `ntoskrnl` project have 2500 types when my `fltMgr.sys` only has 400?

Answer (score 3):

I needed to load the types from `ntoskrnl.exe` into `fltMgr.sys` using <kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>Load File</kbd> -> <kbd>Load PDB File</kbd>.